# Beacon and Flutter can works?

Tags: flutter, beacon

I have a question, I want to buy a beacon and send the signal from the beacon to the flutter application and then do something.

Is that possible with flutter?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I tried https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon for myself interest once when covid-19 declared a pandemic by WHO to solve Handshake problem.

I was converting the existing device as a beacon and then used "flutter_beacon" package to get the list of beacons in a defined region. So yeah, it is possible to do it flutter also. You can customize it as per your need further. But basic things are possible like getting the list of beacons in reason.

Answer (score 0):

If asked whether or not, the answer is yes. but there are some obstacles or limits, such as Bluetooth will not scan in the background as in this [article](https://www.wired.com/story/apple-google-bluetooth-contact-tracing-covid-19/#:%7E:text=Until%20now%2C%20however,the%20project%27s%20spokespeople.), this is indeed from Android and IOS which causes the limit. I am also working on this project, but there are still some problems as I have described above.

This link also can help [Beacon scanning in background - Android O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371372/beacon-scanning-in-background-android-o/51372392#51372392)